# How do I watch my own videos?

Tags: youtube, youtube-studio

Google moved My Videos section to YouTube Studio, I can't actually figure out a way to make a video I've uploaded *play*, let alone find a link to it. I see all sorts of options to change the thumbnail, description etc., but not the most important one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the YouTube Studio, if you hover above an entry, it shows a quicklink to the watch page (the YouTube icon), as well as a ... next to it, which allows you to get shortlinks to share on social media.

[image]

The Studio is still in beta, so send feedback if you want a link to your video somewhere else, too – it's more likely that they'll make changes to the system now.